# Recover exFAT filesystem after bad fsck operation

Tags: data-recovery, fsck, exfat

I spotted a message in dmesg: "Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.", and so I ended up running a command: `doas fsck /dev/sda`. This produced some errors, which I promptly ignored:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.38.1
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
Superblock has an invalid journal (inode 8).
Clear<y>? yes
*** journal has been deleted ***

fsck.ext2: Inode checksum does not match inode while reading bad blocks inode
This doesn't bode well, but we'll try to go on...
```

This took a LOT of "y"s, so I interrupted fsck and switched over to `doas fsck -y /dev/sda`. After this operation, KDE displayed the files as completely empty. At this point I panicked and made a backup (`dd if=/dev/sda of=$HOME/Downloads/tmp-backup`), but I'm afraid that the damage was done already. The only other remaining data I have of this drive is the original UUID of partition `/dev/sda1` ("E7BF-36AA"), and I have the bulk of the commands I executed in a log file.

Is it still possible to recover my data? if so, how?

Comment: I suspect the answer is “no”, but I don’t know conclusively. You could try PhotoRec, and perhaps `exfatfsck` (on `sda1`, not `sda`, but that might be difficult since your partition table is probably gone; note too that `exfatfsck` would likely end up being destructive here).

Comment: Before rebooting, record the contents of `/proc/partitions`. By running a filesystem check on `/dev/sda`, you may have corrupted your bootloader and/or partition table. A saved `/proc/partitions` list should be helpful in recovering the partitioning.

Comment: fsck is short for file system crunch kill... especially if it starts asking questions. Never say y without a backup / snapshot / overlay in place. Sometimes it's too late even if it doesn't ask... it's difficult to say what the damage is and whether it can be recovered. If you're lucky, if you ran fsck on the wrong device (whole disk instead of partition), depending on the partition offset, it might have protected some exfat metadata. There is {fsck,dump,tune}.exfat (in exfatprogs) or exfatfsck (exfat-utils) not sure which is better, don't use either without backup.

Comment: If it's still in `/proc/partitions`, you can get the exact partition offsets from sysfs `head /sys/block/*/*/{start,size}`